# Swift 3 and UserDefaults

Tags: swift3, nsuserdefaults

I have a fair amount of code that looks something like this...

```
let wantsIgnored = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ViewShowIgnoredElements") ?? true
```

The idea was that if the defaults didn't include that key, it would still get a reasonable default value. This worked fine in **Swift 2**, but in **Swift 3** it warns...

```
Left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'Double', so the right side is never used
```

So it seems that `UserDefaults.standard.bool` will *always* return a value, which I guess makes sense if it's a Bool. Ok fine, but what is the best way to solve this problem? I could check every key with `objectForKey`, but that makes the code much messier. Or I could not do this check at all, and make sure that every key is in the initial set of defaults, by hand I guess.

I'm sure I'm not the only one to have faced this, any canonical solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you would think this as *messy*, but you can write something like this:

```
let wantsIgnored = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "ViewShowIgnoredElements") as? Bool ?? true
```

Please try.

Comment: That's not messy at all, I really like it!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
let wantsIgnored = UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ViewShowIgnoredElements")
```

Then to change it:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "ViewShowIgnoredElements")
```

And to call it:

```
let xxxx = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ViewShowIgnoredElements")
```

or:

```
func boolTest (_myBool: Bool){
    if _myBool{
       //do something
    }
}

//and call that function
boolTest(_myBool: UserDefault.standard.bool(forKey: "ViewShowIgnoredElements"))
```